# Why am I getting 'null' results from Laravel 'hasOne' relationship?

Tags: laravel

User Table `users`:

```
id
email
password
```

Post table `posts`

```
id
user_id
title
body
```

here I am using Post Model

My User Model contains:

```php
public function posts()
{  
  return $this->hasOne('App\Post');
}
```

Comment: Where did you get null results. post the error. and particular controller function.

Comment: In php artisan tinker when i try to access relationship  using App\User:find(1)->Post .I always get null .

Comment: Your method was posts() but in tinker you are trying with post then how it will work. Also as i see you are giving the hasOne relation this method name should be post(). And here is another thing that one user can get many posts. So the relation should be hasMany. In this case your method should be posts. So ultimately, either change your method name post() from posts() or change the relation hasMany from hasOne.

Answer (score 1):

Change your relationship to `hasMany`

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

And make sure that the user actually has some posts attached in the Database

Also make sure to setup a foreign key in your `posts` migration

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    // ---- Here ------
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

You can use this code to fill in some posts in order to test

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    App\User::first()->posts()->createMany([
        ['title' => 'Example Title', 'body' => 'Example Body'],
        ['title' => 'Another Title', 'body' => 'Another Body'],
    ]);
});
```

Now you can retrieve the collection of posts for the first user like this

```php
Route::get('/posts', function () {
    return App\User::first()->posts;
});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function name is case sensitive.  In your User model, you defined it as `posts` but are trying to access it with `Post`.  Since there is no method in your User model named `Post`, it returns `null` rather than throwing an error.

Also, as others have recommended, I think you want a `hasMany()` relationship here instead of a `hasOne()`.  Once you fix that, access the relationship in Tinker like this:

```php
>>> User::find(1)->posts
```

Comment: i tried same procedure for more than 50 times.But still it is not working